# how to add sonar sensor to pioneer3at robot in standalone version of gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I want to add sonar sensor to pioneer3at robot in standalone version of gazebo, i don't want to use ros, just i want to work with standalone version of gazebo and i want to test my navigation algorithm, how can i add sonar sensor to my simulated pioneer3at robot and how can i get data of it? can any one help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2773/how-to-add-sonar-sensor-to-pioneer3at-robot-in-standalone-version-of-gazebo/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There isn't a sonar sensor in Gazebo yet. It's in the todo list

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-03**:
Is it done yet?  Gazebo status says it's done in 1.9 but I don't see it in any tutorials or examples.  http://gazebosim.org/#status